# Instantiate generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class which looks like:

```
public class Entry<Key,Value> {

    private Key k;
    private Value v;

    public Entry(Key k , Value v)
    {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public Key getKey()
    {
        return k;
    }

    public Value getValue()
    {
        return v;
    }

}
```

I am trying to instantiate an instance of this class when my application runs. I only know the class types of Key and Value when my program runs. For example, I only know that Key and Value class types will be String.class and Integer.class. Is there a way to instantiate an Entry with this information ? If not , what could I do to create entries dynamically ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you don't actually have instances of `k` and `v`? You need those to call the constructor (has nothing to do with generics).

Comment: Generics are a compile time concept.

Comment: I do have instances of K and V. I want to do something like Entry<String,String> entry = new Entry<String,String>( "a" , "b" ), only using the Class information , here String.class. Is that possible?

Comment: What would a use of that look like?  What possible code would give you an object of a type you don't know at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

A program is like

```
String key = getFromSomewhere();
Integer value = someMethodResult();
```

means that you do know a type at compile time that is better than `Object`. So you can do

```
Entry<String,Integer> entry = new Entry<String,Integer>(key, value);
```

as well. There is no "not knowing the type at runtime", you will always know that an instance is at least `Object` and that's something you can use in generic classes as well. You don't need to use the concrete runtime type.